# Detect if running in a script

Tags: scripting

Is there a reliable way to detect if the current code is running within a script?

Note that there are [multiple ways to run a script](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128761/12), such as

```sh
wolframscript -file file.m
wolframscript -script file.m
math -script file.m
```

One might add `math < file.m`, but I do not need to handle this case.

#### "What have you tried?"

- `$BatchInput` is `True` if piping a file to the kernel as in `math < file.m`, but not when using the `math -script file.m`.
- `$ScriptCommandLine` is usually (always?) different from `{}` when using `wolframscript` (either with `-script` or `-file`), but not when using `math -script`.
- `$EvaluationEnvironment` is `"Script"` with `wolframscript 0file`, but it is `"Session"` with `math -script` and `wolframscript -script`.

Best effort so far:

```
$inScript := $BatchInput || ($EvaluationEnvironment === "Script") || MemberQ[$CommandLine, "-script"]
```

Comment: How about using `$FrontEnd`. In the tests I did, it is `Null` when evaluated in a script.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I am not looking to check if there is a front end present, but whether we're running interactive or in a script. Mathematica can be run interactively in command line mode, without a front end.  It can also have an invisible front end attached when running in a script, but using `UsingFrontEnd` for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi BTW if you want to check for the availability of a notebook interface, you can use `$Notebooks` (which is `True|False`)